# How To Change Included Toolbar Title And Drawable?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar, android-drawable

I have a hard time finding on how to change the `Toolbar` title and it's drawable in every and each `Activity`.

There is something on `Android` Documentation that states that to minimize `APK` size. It is recommended to **re-used** components.

I create a separate layout, and `<include layout=""/>` to each of my `Activities` like Help, About , and etc. I also put `android:label="Title"` on `Manifest` File.

**Toolbar.xml**

[image: tool]

My Main:

[image: main]

How do I access this included `Toolbar` **DRAWABLE and TITLE** in my `Activities` ?

Update: I removed `ActionBar` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Toolbar`. So no need to do anything with `ActionBar`. Just set your `Toolbar` as `supportActionBar`. Then set title and icon to your `Toolbar`.

Use the below code:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.Toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
setTitle("About");
getSupportActionBar.setIcon(R.id.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
```

And, **Remove** all your `mActionBar` codes. Hope this helps.

Comment: I just did what you did, but the `drawable` that I see is the one that I set in my toolbar.xml `app:navigationIcon=" "` (For viewing purpose only). Even if I remove this, no drawable would replace this one, even in running on actual device.

Comment: "Even if I remove this, no drawable would replace this one" Removing app:navigationIcon from toolbar doesn't remove the icon ? Please explain.

Comment: No. I mean, I included `app:navigationIcon` on my toolbar layout so that in would reflect the drawable in preview. In my several apps, coding in java - toolbar drawable (not in separate layout) is superior than `app:navigationIcon`. So even if I put `app:navigationIcon=" "` still what is in code it will override it leaving the `app:nav` useless. What is in java code will be obeyed. But I don't want that one. I want to achieve single layout toolbar for all.

Comment: So, you want to get a preview by app:navigationIcon and when you run the code you wanna see the icon which is set programatically. But you are getting app:navigation icon, is that it ?

Comment: It's is good now, still I use the two - `Toolbar` and `ActionBar` . The Title I set it on `Manifest` - `android:label = " " `. :) I removed the `ActionBar` - icon and replaced `Toolbar` - navigationIcon programmatically.

Comment: Glad to know. :) NB - mActionBar is here actually the toolbar (mActionBar = getSupportActionBar(); ). Though your result will be same, it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

well you set the support action to your custom toolbar,yet you ignore it and use mActionBar, see where i am going with this? setIcon , and setTitle should all be called relative to your custom toolbar.